# Not getting the input I want

Tags: python, input

> Now the problem arises from my if statements, even if I type "Yes", it would still say "Invalid input" and execute my main() function all over again. Not sure what is wrong.Not sure if I'm making an incorrect use of the if, elif statements.

```
condition=input("What is the condition of the phone(New or Used)?")
        if(condition != "New") or (condition != "new"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()
        elif(condition != "Used") or (condition != "used"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()


        gps=input("Does the phone have gps(Yes or No)?")
        if(gps != "Yes") or (gps != "yes"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()
        elif(gps != "No") or (gps != "no"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()


        wifi=input("Does the phone have wifi(Yes or No)?")
        if(wifi != "Yes") or (wifi != "yes"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()
        elif(wifi != "No") or (wifi != "no"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()


        camera=input("Does the phone have a camera(Yes or No)?")
        if(camera != "Yes") or (camera != "yes"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()
        elif(camera != "No") or (camera != "no"):
            print("Invalid input")
            return main()
```

Comment: Your code shows a fundamental lack of understanding on the subject of combining multiple conditions in an "if statement". Better do some more googling.

Comment: For python 2 replace the "input" with "raw_input"

Comment: Let's say you type "Yes", think what will be the result of the first check. It is false so execution drops to the "elif"

Comment: What does the program do actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is doing exactly what it was written to do. After every `input()` line, it executes the following:

```
print("Invalid input")
return main()
```

For example, take your first code block:

```
condition=input("What is the condition of the phone(New or Used)?")
if(condition != "New") or (condition != "new"):
    print("Invalid input")
    return main()
elif(condition != "Used") or (condition != "used"):
    print("Invalid input")
    return main()
```

Say you enter `New` at the prompt, so `condition` now has the value `"New"`. The first test in the `if` statement will yield `False` - `"New" != "New"` is false, because in fact `"New"` **does equal** `"New"`. The next condition after the `or` is now tested and returns `True` (because `"New"` does in fact not equal `"new"`), so the block is executed, printing `"Invalid input"` and running `main()` all over again.

Comment: Dear Downvoters: I'd love to address your concerns with my answer, but you didn't state any. Now I'm sad :(

Comment: Not exactly a helpful answer as the obvious problem is a lack of understanding conditional programming. op already suspects that this is the problem and your answer didn't help so now he is sad :(

Comment: @StillLearnin I am now :) happy with my answer. Hopefully others and the OP will be as well.

Comment: The first `if` is not actually skipped. `(condition != "New") or (condition != "new")` is True since at least one of the tests must be True.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto I'm really tired tonight. You are correct, I missed that. Now I'm going to bed...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition != "New") or (condition != "new"):
```

This will always be True, since `condition` can't be both "New" and "new". At least one of the comparisons will be True, making the whole expression equal to True. That can be fixed by switching the `or` to an `and`. The same follows for every other condition in your code.

Even if you change the the check to

```
(condition != "New") and (condition != "new")
```

you still have another problem. If `condition == "New"`, then the check is False and evaluations jumps to the `elif`.

```
elif (condition != "Used") and (condition != "used"):
```

The `elif` must be False, since `condition` is not "Used" nor "used". You can fix this by putting all of the tests in the same if:

```
if (condition != "New") and (condition != "new") and (condition != "Used") and (condition != "used"):
```

---

However, a more idiomatic way to do this is:

```
if condition not in ["New", "new", "Used", "used"]:
    print("Invalid input")
    return main()
```

This prints "Invalid input" if `condition` is not one of the strings in `["New", "new", "Used", "used"]`.

Even better would be to ignore casing altogether. To do that, just call `.lower()` on `input`:

```
condition = input("What is the condition of the phone(New or Used)?").lower()
```

You can then check

```
if condition not in ["new", "used"]:
```

and your code will accept inputs such as "new", "uSED", "NeW" and fail (`print("Invalid input")`) for other inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for posting a sloppy question like that, this is my very first post. I appreciate the explanation and effort put into this. Thank you!!!!!